# List of different types as argument

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to pass 2 lists of different types (which depends of use case) from fragment to adapter constructor, in my one recyclerview.

So in BindViewHolder I should take that list of necessary type, get 1 item and set it to viewholder.

What can be the best way to insert "abstract" list type ? I try to do it with Object, but it seems to be wrong way.

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Object> articles;

public MyAdapter(List<Object> articles, Context context) {
    this.articles = articles;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
// ???
    Object article = getOneArticleFromArticles(articles, position);

//  here in in setText I only can get title from my concrete entity type 
    holder.title.setText(article.getTitle());
...
```

first entity:

```
public class Foo {
private String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
}
```

second entity:

```
public class Bar {
private String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
  }
```

Usage

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(#response items from Foo#, getActivity());

adapter = new MyAdapter(#response items from Bar#, getActivity());
```

Comment: Do all the types that might appear in the list have a `getTitle()` method?  Perhaps you should define an interface that has this method, and use that interface as the type parameter for the list.

Comment: @DavidWallace they are a bit different (Foo has String image, Bar - String Description)

Comment: If there are some that don't have `getTitle()`, then how will your code know what to do if `getTitle()` isn't present?  But if they _do_ all have `getTitle()`, then just define an interface with `getTitle()` in it, have all your types implement the interface, then use the interface as the list's type parameter.

Comment: Do you display items of both types at the same time in your RecyclerView ? Like some items are `Foo` and the others are `Bar`.

Comment: @PhilippeA yes, they are applied  from retrofit service and rxjava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the question and comments, you want something that will provide a common way to get the title through `getTitle()` but will also allow you to have other methods for each "implementation" class.

An interface is a simple way to do it. You can define `getTitle()` in the interface and make each class implement it.

You can then use this interface as a type for parameter passed to the adapter.